# R: Plot flow cytometry data using biexponential axes

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to visualize flow cytometry data in R. I want to display data using biexponential axes as employed [by FlowJo](http://www.flowjo.com/v76/en/displaytransformwhy.html), which are logarithmic at high positive and high negative values but linear about the origin.

Currently I am using log axes, but run into trouble with negative values:

```
Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  1 x value <= 0 omitted from logarithmic plot
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  6 y values <= 0 omitted from logarithmic plot
```

Is there any way to do this or will I have to make do with log axes?

Comment: If you provide an example it should be possible to build an answer first transforming values in specified ranges, then using `plot` while suppressing the default axes and then using `axis`. But you will need to clearly specify what you expect to see at the "join-points" for the three different regimes. That link does not do a good job of detailing the transformations and cites a paper with a link that is dead.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/7ddCyXGlKiM).

Comment: @BondedDust The biexponential, or hyperlog transformation is described [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cyto.a.20114/full#sec1-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own custom scaling transformation function. You'll just have to label your axis accordingly. For example,

```
y<-(-1000:1000)

xform<-function(x) ifelse(abs(x)<10,x/10,sign(x)*log10(abs(x)))
ixform<-function(x) ifelse(abs(x)<1,x*10,sign(x)*10^abs(x))

plot(xform(y),yaxt="n",type="l")
yticks<-axTicks(2)
axis(2, at=yticks, labels=ixform(yticks))
```

[image: custom scale]

This is just an example transformation but should provide the idea of what is possible and one way to go about it.