# R: (kind of) log axis, i.e. axis with (...-10^1,0,10^1,...) , displaying negative values

Tags: r

I have a data-set containing many small (~100), but some bigger (~10<sup>6</sup>) values as well. But the few big points (Which are not that important, but shouldn't be left out) stretch the whole axis.

For positive values i'd use `log="y"`...
But now, i'd love to get an axis like "...-10<sup>2</sup>, -10<sup>1</sup>, 0, 10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>2</sup>...".

Is there a(n easy) possibility to do this?
Do i have to loop through my data set, mapping all negative numbers x to -log(|x|)?   And what to do with the y-axis afterwards?

[image: The dataset actually printed]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32231474/1756702

Comment: Thank you.. an hour of searching, still too dumb to find it...